# How to write a dockerfile such that the resulting dockerimage cannot connect to the network

Tags: docker, networking

I want to set up a docker container with an instance of ubuntu and I'd like to deactivate all network connections for that instance.

I know that this can be done when running the container (i.e. by "--network none"), but I'd like to know if it is possible to create a dockerfile such that the resulting container will always be unable to connect to the network.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do in the Dockerfile. The output of a docker build is an image, which consists of the filesystem layers, and the default configuration. That configuration, described in the [OCI image-spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/config.md) includes things like:

- default user
- environment variables
- volumes
- entrypoint

However, network settings are not part of it, and adding it now would be nontrivial since you have images used by tools like Kubernetes where the networking is at the pod rather than container level and handled by any number of CNI implementations.

Comment: Somewhere on the internet I've read that it might be possible by removing the gateway from /etc/network/interfaces. Would that be sufficient to block any network access (and what exactly would I have to do)?

Comment: @auto_driving_q you can try and see if it works for you. I don't believe it will because container networking is setup without using files inside the container filesystem.